# Is there a free portable version of F-Prot Antivirus available?

Tags: anti-virus, portable

I'm looking for a portable AV for my USB-Stick (currently using ClamWinAV), and heard that F-Prot is good. Do they offer a free (earlier) version with up-to-date virus definitions, if so where can I download it?

Answer (score 0):

F-Prot is not available for free (only a trial version) nor in a portable version.

However, [Pen Drive Apps has a whole list of portable anti-virus software](http://www.pendriveapps.com/software/portable-antivirus-firewall/) for you to pick from!

Looking at other recommendations like this, ClamWin should be a good pick.

> **[ClamWin Portable – Antivirus to Go](http://www.pendriveapps.com/clamwin-portable/)**
> [image]
>
> No computer should be without good
> antivirus software. One nice Portable
> Antivirus solution is ClamWin
> Portable. ClamWin Portable is Free
> Open Source software that can be
> installed to a USB flash drive, iPod,
> portable hard drive or even a CD. You
> can then take it with you to run from
> any Windows computer to diagnosing and
> scan for viruses without leaving any
> traces behind.

Answer (score 0):

See [Portable Antivirus – Ultimate List of Best USB Anti Virus](http://thepcsecurity.com/ultimate-list-of-portable-antiviruses-for-your-usb/).

It has a list of 9 antiviruses and a nice image :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(There *used* to be a free DOS version of F-Prot, but its time has long since passed ;-).)
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:QlkcECKOiScJ:www.f-prot.com/download/download_fpdos.html+f-prot+dos&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=seamonkey-a